# Create Power Automate Flow to sync files between 2 sharepoints with dynamic folder names being added

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I would like to sync certain files between 2 different SharePoint libraries.

**As source SharePoint** I have a folder structure /Shared Documents/Projects where sub-folders are dynamically added at random times eg Project1 and Project2 etc. Within these folders a word document is added.

**As destination SharePoint** I have /Documents/CurrentProjects/Projects and the same sub-folders will be there (dynamically added) eg Project1 and Project2

What I would like is when the Source SharePoint has for example /Shared Documents/Projects/Project3/projectdoc3.docx created or modified then that file is synced to the Destination SharePoint /Documents/CurrentProjects/Projects/Project3/projectdoc3.docx

What I currently have is this

[image]

My questions are

1. how can I dynamically set the destination folder based on the source folder?
2. This currently only copies in one direction, is it possible to sync instead so that if the destination file is modified then the source is also modified?